# MYSQL and PHP Unexpected errors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL and I'm struggling with the problem below:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Pharm_Log set text = ". $bloodtest . " WHERE patient = " . $patientid .;
    if(is_resource($sql) and mysql_num_rows($sql)>0){
```

The problem occurs when I try to close my SQL statement. I know it's something to do with brackets and semi colons but every time I change one thing, it messes up another. Could somebody please help me?

Comment: I think it is the last dot just before the semi colon, try removing that

Comment: Also, `$sql` is a string, not a resource. You need to execute the query first to get a resource. And `mysql_num_rows()` is not suitable for UPDATE queries.

Comment: All `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` functions instead.

Comment: If any of the answers helped your, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

here are the things you need to do:

- remove the last period before the semi colon
- wrap the string literal with single quotes
- execute the query using `mysql_query`

code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Pharm_Log set text = '$bloodtest'  WHERE patient = " . $patientid;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(is_resource($result ) and mysql_num_rows($result )>0) { ... }
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dot before the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its the last `.` thats causing a syntax error. Plus you need to surround non int values in quotes, Also its important that you dont forget to add mysql_real_escape_string else problems will arise, you should also use PDO or mysqli with prepared querys.

```
<?php 
$sql = "UPDATE Pharm_Log 
        SET `text`='".mysql_real_escape_string($bloodtest)."' 
        WHERE patient = '".mysql_real_escape_string($patientid)."'";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firsdt, remove the last dot on the first line, since you aren't connecting any string at the end. Should look like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Pharm_Log set text = ". $bloodtest . " WHERE patient = " . $patientid;
```

Are you doing a query to the SQL server? If not, the variable `$sql` doesn't do anything, so add:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

And change your last code line to process the result of the query instead

```
if(is_resource($result) && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `.` at the end. Change it into,

```
$sql = "UPDATE Pharm_Log set text = ". $bloodtest . " WHERE patient = " . $patientid;
```

Comment: Guys thanks alot for the quick help!